# How to truncate a MongoDB collection via the DoctrineMongoDBBundle?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a mongoDB collection and I want to programatically truncate it (remove all documents in this collection). I did this:

```
    $collection = $this
        ->container
        ->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

    $document_manager = $this
        ->container
        ->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getManager();

    if($override){
        $document_manager->remove($collection);
```

Where *User* is the name of collection. But it does not work. How to properly remove all documents from a collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get a collection:

```
$collection = $document_manager->getDocumentCollection('AppBundle:User'); // or just a class name
```

To [remove](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) all the documents from the collection pass empty array to match all documents:

```
$collection->remove([]);
```

To [drop](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) the collection:

```
$collection->drop();
```